# cual es el error con el código ? problemas con el array

Tags: java, poo

Alguien sabe por que al ejecutar esto va todo bien hasta que termina el método `Procesos_aaa()` ?. Luego de eso me pide que inserte un dato, cuando se supone que debería listar los datos del `array`, y cuando inserto un dato al azar para probar que pasa, me muestra los valores del `array` como `null`. Ademas, la cantidad de datos que muestra como `null` son acordes a la vez que ingrese un dato al azar, no a la cantidad que ingrese la primera vez.
Acá dejo el código:

```
package stackoverflowq;
public class StackOverFlowQ {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Ingresa la cantidad total de procesos q deseas cerrar antes de " + "+ apagar/suspender/hibernar +" + " la pc: ");
        StackOverFlow1 obj1 = new StackOverFlow1 ();
        obj1.Procesos_aaa();

        StackOverFlow2 obj2 = new StackOverFlow2 ();
        obj2.Procesos_lista();
    }
}

package stackoverflowq;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StackOverFlow1 {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String Procesos[] = new String [in.nextInt()];  
        public void Procesos_aaa() {
            in.nextLine();
            for(int con = 0; con < Procesos.length; con++) {
                System.out.print("Ingresa el nombre del " + ++con + " proceso, (x ej: chrome.exe) ");
                Procesos[--con] = in.nextLine();
            }
        }

    public String[] getProcesos() {
        return Procesos;
    }
}

package stackoverflowq;
public class StackOverFlow2 {
    StackOverFlow1 obj = new StackOverFlow1();
    String[] temp = obj.getProcesos();  
        public void Procesos_lista() {
            int con = 0;  
            while(con < temp.length) {
                if (con == 0) {
                    System.out.print("los procesos que usted desea detener son: " + temp[con] + ", ");
                } else if (con > 0 && con < (temp.length - 1) ) {
                    System.out.print(temp[con] + ", ");
                } else if (con == (temp.length - 1) ) {
                    System.out.println(temp[con] + ".");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
            con++;
            }           
        }  
}
```

Comment: En tu **main** estas instanciando la clase `StackOverFlow1` y a su vez utilizando el método `Procesos_aaa` pero en ningún momento asignas el resultado de Procesos_aaa a una variable; además Procesos_aaa no devuelve nada... será eso?

Comment: @SMati000 también instancias un objeto de tipo StackOverFlow1 en tu clase StackOverFlow2, y de ese objeto quieres recoger el array el cual estará vacío, ya que no es el mismo objeto del main.

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera el método `Procesos_aaa()` asigna valores a ese array `Procesos[]` y el método `getProcesos()` se encarga de devolverlos.

Comment: Esta claro que tiene un método que devuelve los procesos pero ese método jamás lo invoca en el main :/

Comment: No le coloques resuelta al título de la pregunta, es suficiente con aceptar la respuesta que te ayudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cual es el error del código

El problema está en la llamada a getProcesos(), que lo haces en la clase `StackOverFlow2` sobre un array vacío. 
Puedes bien, llamar al método `Procesos_aaa()` en la clase `StackOverFlow2` y a raíz de ahí recoger ese array. Y en el main quitar u omitir la creación del objeto de tipo `StackOverFlow1`.

---

**Te dejo el código al completo:**

```
public class StackOverFlowQ {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Ingresa la cantidad total de procesos que deseas cerrar antes de apagar/suspender/hibernar la pc:");

        StackOverFlow2 obj2 = new StackOverFlow2();
        obj2.Procesos_lista();
    }
}

class StackOverFlow1 {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String Procesos[] = new String [in.nextInt()];  
        public void Procesos_aaa() {
            in.nextLine();
            for(int con = 0; con < Procesos.length; con++) {
                System.out.print("Ingresa el nombre del " + ++con + " proceso, (x ej: chrome.exe) ");
                Procesos[--con] = in.nextLine();
            }
        }

    public String[] getProcesos() {
        return Procesos;
    }
}

class StackOverFlow2 {
    String[] temp;

    public StackOverFlow2() {
        StackOverFlowPrueba1 obj = new StackOverFlowPrueba1();
        obj.Procesos_aaa();
        temp = obj.getProcesos();
    }

    public void Procesos_lista() {
        int con = 0;
        while (con < temp.length) {
            if (con == 0) {
                System.out.print("los procesos que usted desea detener son: " + temp[con] + ", ");
            } else if (con > 0 && con < (temp.length - 1)) {
                System.out.print(temp[con] + ", ");
            } else if (con == (temp.length - 1)) {
                System.out.println(temp[con] + ".");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
            con++;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Una prueba de tu código...**

```
Ingresa la cantidad total de procesos que deseas cerrar antes de apagar/suspender/hibernar la pc:
4
Ingresa el nombre del 1 proceso, (x ej: chrome.exe) proceso1
Ingresa el nombre del 2 proceso, (x ej: chrome.exe) proceso2
Ingresa el nombre del 3 proceso, (x ej: chrome.exe) proceso3
Ingresa el nombre del 4 proceso, (x ej: chrome.exe) proceso4
los procesos que usted desea detener son: proceso1, proceso2, proceso3, proceso4.
```